# Запуск модуля заполнения словаря из settings.py

Tags: python, django, settings

В файл настроек Django settings.py добавил пустой словарь: REG_DCS = {}
Его должен заполнить модуль reg_dcs.py
Собственно не могу прийти к адекватному решению запуска данного модуля автоматически при запуске Питона.
А если смотреть глубже то я думаю нужно при рестарте боевого сервера запускать модуль reg_dcs.py дабы обновить словарь REG_DCS

Comment: `import reg_dcs` в `settings.py`? Хотя сложно что-то внятное сказать, не видя кода.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю вашу проблему - нужно в файле reg_dcs.py создать функцию, которая обновит словарь (это в том случае, если необходимо именно обновить словарь). По правильному - лучше создать функцию которая инициализирует REG_DCS.

```
from reg_dcs import init_dcs

REG_DCS = init_dcs()
```

Comment: А разве в settings можно импортировать функцию и использовать ее?